# Insertar datos donde exista el id ya definido! en codeigniter

Tags: php, insert

espero que hayan tenido una bonita navidad.

resulta que tengo una tabla que se llama *votaciones* con los siguientes campos:

*id*,
*opcion*,
*nombre*,
*correo*,
*rut* ,
*cond1*,
*cond2*,
*fecha*

es un sistema de votación entonces al votar se guarda en al db el `ID` y la `opcion` más adelante si quiere el individuo se registra y para eso necesito un *INSERT nombre,corre.. WHERE ID = ID*

intente con este código:modelo

```
function InsertRegistro($id,$data){
   $this->db->insert('votaciones',$data);
   $this->db->where("id",$id);
}
```

desde mi controller:

```
public function registro() {

    $id = $this - > input - > post('id');

    $data = array(

        'nombre' => $this - > input - > post('nombre'),
        'correo' => $this - > input - > post('correo'),
        'rut' => $this - > input - > post('rut'),
        'cond1' => $this - > input - > post('cond1'),
        'cond2' => $this - > input - > post('cond2'),

    );

    $this - > load - > model('Prontomodel');
    $this - > Prontomodel - > InsertRegistro($id, $data);

}
```

me inserta datos pero me borra el *id* y luego no me deja insertar, algo estoy haciendo mal, la cosa es que estoy aprendiendo codeigniter y agradeceria que me enseñaran a como hacerlo, gracias.

Comment: Yo creo que deberías agregar también el id en tu array $data para que se agrege a la base de datos.

Comment: okey, lo probare

Comment: Vale, coméntame si tienes cualquier problema.

Comment: al poner el id dentro del data como deberia de ir esta linea   $this->db->where("id",$id); en el modelo?

Comment: Yo lo que haría sería recuperar el id fuera del array y después asignarlo dentro del array. `'id' => $id`, de esta manera también se lo podrías pasar al modelo.

Comment: pero si yo pongo el id dentro del data me intentara insertar el id que ya existe y al ser primary key, me lanzara un error de duplicado, yo necesito insertar los datos al id ya existente

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/50727/discussion-between-error404-and-hernan-humana).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo que puedo entender, realmente lo que quieres hacer es una actualización de un registro de la base de datos, no una inserción de un registro nuevo. De hecho, en `MySQL` no se puede utilizar la clausula `WHERE` en una inserción de datos, así que supongo que aquí será parecido (no sé que motor de base de datos usa `codeigniter`).

Por lo tanto, tu tendrías que utilizar un `UPDATE` (actualización) en vez de un `INSERT` (inserción), en el cual si que está permitido la clausula `WHERE`.

Tu código sería, según la **[documentación](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide2/database/active_record.html#update)**, de este modo:

```
function InsertRegistro($id,$data){
   $this->db->where('id',$id);
   $this->db->update('votaciones',$data);
}
```